# How do I implement a duration variable for my Windows Forms App?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application that connects to a USB port.

In the method, there would be a while(!connected) to attempt to connect to the port endlessly.

How do I create a TimeSpan(?) variable to limit the connection to around maybe 10 seconds before it stops trying to connect and display a messagebox saying

> "Connection failed. Please try again."

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just record the start time as a DateTime?

```
var connectionStartTime = DateTime.Now
```

You can then periodically check the connection duration:

```
var duration = DateTime.Now - connectionStartTime;
```

You can then simply test the following

```
if (duration.TotalSeconds > 10.0) { do something }
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your response. i have updated my questions above. any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx